# Need to implement jquery in Struts2 frame work

Tags: struts2-jquery

I need to need to implement jquery(like auto complete in search box) in Struts2 frame work, So I want to know which is best way to implement use jquery plugin for struts2 or simply add jquery in struts 2??
   Any good tutorial to start with??

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the plugin as it provides a lot more than just jQuery - it gives you JSP tags that do most of the work for you.
[This](http://struts2-jquery-plugin.109969.n3.nabble.com/working-example-for-struts2-jquery-td3470518.html) has a simple example to get you started. There is also a [showcase](http://struts2-jquery-plugin.109969.n3.nabble.com/working-example-for-struts2-jquery-td3470518.html) which provides example code for all the various tags.